# How could I encode a string of 1s and 0s for transport?

Tags: c#, string, encoding, binary

For a genetic algorithm application, I'm using a whole load of binary strings. Most of the time they literally take the form of `01001010110`, so that they can be mated, mutated and "crossed-over".

For transport and storage however, this seems wasteful. What's the simplest way to encode this as a shorter string?

I'm guessing this is pretty trivial, but I'm not sure where to start looking.

**Update:** I actually need to end up with another string: one of the transport requests will be GET requests.

Comment: Will you be transmitting between machines of different architectures?

Comment: Almost certainly not - why do you ask?

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain pointed out that my solution might run into problems if you were transmitting across architectures.

Comment: Are they always the same size, 10 digits long?

Comment: For a given iteration of the application they're the same length, but not necessarily 10.

Comment: What is the longest they could be?

Comment: I don't get it.  Storing them in a byte[] isn't just efficient for transport, it is also *much* more efficient for your algorithm.

Comment: Abe: realistically not more than a couple of dozen. Hans: That may well be the case, but most operations will be performed at the bit level.

Comment: @Tom, that's a reason to have them in a byte[] not a reason not to.

Comment: You guys might like to trundle over to this resultant question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3943858/50151

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest would be to take each digit and treat it as a bit. Each group of 8 bits can be stored in a byte. Then you can send it as a stream of bytes. You will also need to store the length of the original string so that you can distinguish between "0" and "00".

Here is one way you could write the conversion from string to a byte array:

```
byte[] convertToBytes(string s)
{
    byte[] result = new byte[(s.Length + 7) / 8];

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        result[i] <<= 1;
        if (c == '1')
            result[i] |= 1;
        j++;
        if (j == 8)
        {
            i++;
            j = 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Reversing the operation is very similar.

If you need to transmit the data as a string you can [base 64 encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) the resulting byte array.

You may also want to consider keeping it in this form in memory too. This will be much more efficient than storing it as a string where each digit is stored as a 2 byte character. You are using roughly 16 times more memory than you need to for storing your data. The disadvtange is that it is slightly more difficult to use in this form, so if you have enough memory then what you are currently doing might be just fine.

Answer (score 2):

What about converting it to it's base 10 integer equivalent?

```
int myBin = Convert.ToInt32("01001010110", 2);
```

[Convert.ToInt32() documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx)

Comment: You run the risk of issues of endienness and sign issues if you are transmitting between machines of different architectures. It would be safer to use bytes.

Comment: This isn't true, a string doesn't have endianness.  Most significant bit is always on the left.

Answer (score 1):

I would just store them as an array of bytes and use a helper function to translate between the byte array version and the string version.

Comment: If the string itself is in ASCII form and there's no packing going on to fit 8 bits/byte (and instead just storing 1 bit per byte) this won't really save much space.

Comment: I meant store it 8 string intagers to one byte.

Comment: Would I be able to get a string representation of the byte array?

Comment: Yes, any time you can convert back to a string, if you really need it.

Answer (score 1):

Or implement [Run length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) or [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding). Both are fairly easy to implement. RLE is by far the easiest, but will in most cases have worse compression ratio. If your data typically has many consecutive characters of the same value, it could still provide a substantial improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Abe Miessler's answer is a good one, but with caveat mentioned in comments.

If 64 bits is not enough to represent your string, then consider using a `BigInt` class
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/BigInt.aspx (you would probably want to add  `to/fromBinary()` extension methods to it. Alternatively represent this as a ... linked list of bytes.

Either approach has the problem of discarding any leading zeroes, so you would want to store the original length as well.