# Binary String to ASCII TEXT String

Tags: c#, binary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Binary To Corresponding ASCII String Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006425/binary-to-corresponding-ascii-string-conversion)

I posted a slimier question before but didn't got a correct answer..

my problem is i have a binary string as

```
00100000011101110110000101101110011101000010000001110100011011110010000001100100011011110111
```

Which im required to convert to `"Normal ASCII String Text"`

I used  `BinaryReader` and read and encode `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII` but im getting the same `0101010` string

```
    byte[] bytearray = b.ReadBytes((int)length);

    System.Text.Encoding encEncoder = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;

    string bb = encEncoder.GetString(bytearray);
```

any help will be grateful !

Comment: -1 for asking for attention in the wrong way. You can edit your original question adding more information instead of asking whole new question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first translate the binary string into a `byte[]` using [How could I encode a string of 1s and 0s for transport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935524/how-could-i-encode-a-string-of-1s-and-0s-for-transport)

next use the [Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx) method to get the actual `System.String`